# Brother MFC-240C Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: scanner, brother

Brother MFC-240C Not scanning to computer. Test page and a document page printed fine. The photo copy part works OK to.

Answer (score 1):

I have sucessfully installed, printed and scanned the brother mfc240c since 8.04, I have found it to work perfectly in 12.04...please make sure to install the correct drivers that can be found here ...http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all make sure your printer/scanner MFC is supported in Ubuntu at the following websites.

For your specific manufacturer click [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersBrother)

All manufacturers can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScanners)

The Sane Projects list of supported devices can be found [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html)

You can find linux drivers made by Brother [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/index.html)

Make sure you do Brothers pre-required procedures by clicking [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/before.html#prereq).
Then Click [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html) to go to Brothers printer cups driver installation guide and [here](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html) to go to Brothers lpr printer installation guide. Follow the guide according to whether you want CUPS or LPR, Brother recommends cups. I have heard following these steps have worked for others and that the MFC print drivers is all you should need on some models to make both work. Mine doesn't work this way. I have never came across one that works this way.

I searched all these websites and couldn't find a Brother MFC-240C scanner that was supported. However, I did see a Brother MFC-7240 and a Brother MFC-230C. So for your sake I hope you made a typo and your device is supported. The photo copy part of the machine is not handled by your computer and should work whether its connected to a computer or not.

This being a brother device I do know that they can be a pain to get both printer and scanning capabilities to work correctly in any Linux distrobution if it isn't supported. I've read where others have the same issue as you with Brother devices, printer works scanner doesn't. I have a brother MFC device that has never worked correctly and it seems never will unless I learn how to write device drivers. I can get it to work if I don't set it up as a printer first. But if the scanner works the printer part never will, and vice versa. So you can try removing the printer set up and driver, disconnect it from the computer. Then reconnect it and try setting it up to scan first. If that works then you can try setting up printer and hope they both work that way. Mine wouldn't. Its one or the other.

Other than what I have already stated the following is basically my experience and some suggestions. I work for a networking/computer repair company and I personally specialize in printer networking and repairs. Always check that the device you have in mind to buy is supported in Linux and Ubuntu before buying. You'll save yourself a possible headache.  I always recommend HP devices for Linux systems, they are usually supported, at least the ones I have came across, and are a snap to get working. Research what other people have bought and have had good experiences with when installing and using in Linux. In my experiences, multi function printers/scanners/fax machines can be a pain to get working correctly if unsupported in any version of Linux. Also, I've found that USB devices work and are easier to configure compared to Parallel devices that hardly ever work for scanning especially. That being said it has been a few years since I've installed any type of MFC on a linux machine because most of our customers use Windows and the ones that use Linux I have to set it up once and they never screw up so I hardly have to fix them again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This user asks how to get their scanner working, but you give instructions on how to install the printer drivers.  Consider revising your answer to be more succinct.