# Brother device in LAN not detected as a scanner but as a printer only since 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scanner, lan, brother

I have two computerrs in the same LAN, where computer A is running Ubuntu 15.10 and computer B is running Ubuntu 16.04. There is a Brother MFC-8860DN multi function center device connected to the network, too. Both machines recognize the MFC-8860DN as a printer. However, machine B does not recognize the Brother as a scanner device, while machine A does.

I've stumbled upon [quite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389636/invalid-argument-brother-scanner-not-working-after-upgrade-brscan2-driver) a [few](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321613) [threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254045/brother-mfc-240c-ubuntu-12-04-1) dealing with similiar issues. However, topics to be found are more or less referring either to outdated Ubuntu versions or to using devices via USB or both.

How to set up the Brother device properly on 16.04? What system output might be helpful?

Best, Bunjip

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem upon upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, it was working fine before.

Brother's tools are correctly detecting the scanner, but not SANE, so you can always scan using `brscan-skey`, the go to your scanner and press the scan button.

I solved the issue by reinstalling the scanner driver with a newer version:

```
sudo apt-get remove brscan4
sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.4-1.amd64.deb
```

then add your scanner

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name="Brother scanner" model="MFC-L2720DW" ip="192.168.1.228"
```

Comment: Solved: reinstalling the scanner driver with newer version solved the problem.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove brscan4

Comment: sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.4-1.amd64.deb, then add your scanner brsaneconfig4 -a name="Brother scanner" model="MFC-L2720DW" ip="192.168.1.228"

Comment: Rather than posting 3 new comments under your own question, you can click the `edit` button under your answer and add the new lines there. Next you can click the `X` button next to your 3 comments and delete them. Thank you and welcome to AskUbuntu.

Comment: This is great info. I suggest editing your answer and adding these steps that worked.

Comment: I'll check this with my machine as soon as I'm back in office, which is not earlier than next week unfortunately. Hope, that works for me too.

Comment: I have MFC-8860DN. Scan used to work in older Ubuntu versions but now on Ubuntu 20.04 it does not work. xsane says "No devices available". I have removed brscan2, downloaded latest version and installed it using sudo dpkg -i brscan2-0.2.5-1.amd64.deb with no change. Chat with Brother the tech said they do not support Linux. I then tried using ControlCenter3 on WIndows 10 and that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the scanner driver for brother, event network scanners, needs libusb-0.1 installed.

```
sudo apt install libusb-0.1
```